# Ошибка при построении модели нейронной сети на TF-IDF и Sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, sklearn

Пытаюсь обучить нейронную сеть определять цену квартиры в зависимости от ее описания.
В csv для тренировки 300.000 квартир с ценами. Засовываю все описания в единую строку, чтобы потом применить метод TF-IDF, определяющий важность каждого слова в таргете.

И уже на этапе формирования этой большой строки выпадает ошибка:

```
Your notebook tried to allocate more memory than is available. It has restarted.
```

Пробовал и с GPU и с TPU на Colab Google - не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло последовательное считывание файла датасета:

```
train = pd.DataFrame()
counter = 1
for num in pd.read_csv('train.csv', chunksize=1000000, low_memory=False):
    print('Reading {}'.format(counter))
    train = pd.concat([train, num], ignore_index=True)
    counter += 1
```

Работает и на Kaggle и в Colab- ошибка, связанная с переполнением памяти, не появляется. Может быть, кому-то пригодится.

Comment: "Засовываю все описания в единую строку" - а где это в вашем коде, я не вижу. Здесь вы решаете проблему чтения `csv` файла целиком, у вас на этом падала ошибка памяти значит, а не на какой-то там единой строке?